# not valid in the context that it is used sql db2 cloud

Tags: sql, db2

[image]

Trying to find the cell with a safety score of 1 however, I am told that:

> 'safety_score is not valid in the context that it is used.

Safety_Score is a column name in the database.

My code was as follows

```
Select * From Schools WHERE safety_score = '1'
```

where am i going wrong?

thanks, :)

Comment: Please show the exact SQL statement you are using and the error message. Yours seems to be cut off at the beginning (there's an opening single quote, but no closing one).

Comment: Error message
"SAFETY_SCORE" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.26.14
Learn more about this error

Comment: SELECT * from schools WHERE Safety_Score = '1';

Comment: What's the exact result (preserving case of characters) of the following query? `select colname from syscat.columns where tabschema='GNK69870' and tabname='SCHOOLS' and lower(colname)='safety_score'`?

Comment: thank you, it results in the showing of the column name 'safety_score' next to a green tick but without the rows of results

Comment: And does it run fine when you run the query `select safety_score from schools`? BTW, you should leave out the single quotes around the '1' (i.e. `WHERE safety_score = 1`), as safety_score is a number, not a string.  Having said that, some, if not most, SQL engines don't care!

Comment: @Daniel If you got the result with characters not all in upper case, then the column was created using an expression with double quotes - "safety_score". This instruct Db2 to preserve case of characters in the column name. The side effect of such a creation is, that you have to use absolutely the same expression **in double quotes** to reference this column. Try `select * from GNK69870.SCHOOLS where "safety_score" = 1`.